# Angular Material - Datepicker make max value a month from selected value

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have two datepickers. One to pick the "fromDate" and the other to pick the 
"toDate". I am excepting the user to first select fromDate, and toDate should have a max value of a month from the fromDate.

The max value will disable users from selecting a date over 30 days from the startDate/fromDate.

Angular material doc #datevalidation
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings

**Html:**

```
<mat-form-field class="datepicker">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="frompicker" placeholder="from" [formControl]="fromDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="frompicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #frompicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="datepicker">
        <input matInput [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="topicker"  placeholder="to" [formControl]="toDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #topicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

**Ts file:**

```
  setMaxDateForCalender(){

    let fullyear = this.datePipe.transform(this.fromDate.value, "yyyy");

    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.fromDate.value.getDate());
    this.maxDate.setMonth(this.fromDate.value.getMonth() + 1);
    this.maxDate.setFullYear(Number(fullyear));

    console.log("Max Date After: " + this.datePipe.transform(this.maxDate, this.dateFormat));
  }
```

I tried different ways to do this, but the max value doesn't seem to trigger after fromDate is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you use Reactive form, formControl or ngModel? where you call the function setMaxDateForCalendar()?

```
//if you're using ReactiveForm
..AFTER you create the form...
this.myForm.get('fromDate').valueChanges
        .subscribe((date:any) => {
            ..use "date", NOT this.myForm.value.fromDate
        })

//If this.fromDate is a FormControl use
this.fromDate.valueChanges
        .subscribe((date:any) => {
            ..use "date", NOT this.fromDate.value
        })
```